# Is there a scope shared between instances of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, scope

Besides the global scope, of course.

---

I have a custom assertion class with a macro to cache a reference to `__FILE__`:

```
#define DEFINE_THIS_FILE \
  static const char THIS_FILE__[] = __FILE__
```

For source code, using the macro is no big deal since each source has its own scope. However, templated classes can't use source code, so I'm forced to do all my ASSERT() calls in the declaration/definition given by TemplateClass.h

If I use my macro outside of the class definition e.g. `Singleton`

```
DEFINE_THIS_FILE;

namespace NE
{
  template<typename T>
  class Singleton
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the macro winds up in the same scope of any code that #includes `Singleton`, and the compiler throws a redefinition error for `THIS_FILE__`. (Of course, this only happens if the other code *also* uses the `DEFINE_THIS_FILE` macro.)

If I put the macro *inside* the declaration, the compiler won't complain but the linker won't be able to find THIS_FILE__ for any given instance of templated class e.g. `Singleton`:

```
namespace NE
{
  template<typename T>
  class Singleton
  {
    constexpr DEFINE_THIS_FILE;     // constexpr modifier required in this case
    ...
  }
}
```

I assume the linker error I get,
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "NE::Singleton<NE::NonTemplateType>::THIS_FILE__"`
is caused by the template instances not existing in the same scope as where `THIS_FILE__` was first defined, Singleton.h

---

## OT: Is there a way to get all instances of my templated type `Singleton` to share a scope (global is unacceptable) so that all instances can use this static const macro?

---

**Edit1**
Further testing confirms: Using the macro `DEFINE_THIS_FILE` *inside each templated method* containing an ASSERT() will compile and run correctly....
In this case, the instances aren't sharing a scope, but have a `static const char THIS_FILE__` defined for each method. This works, but I suspect that it uses as much or more ROM than a std::assert (with its its implied allocation of `__FILE__`).

I'll settle for this until an answer to OT comes about :)

---

**Edit2**
Silly me. Instead of using the workaround listed in edit above, I might as well create another macro, UNCACHED_ASSERT(argsToCheck) that directly uses `__FILE__` instead of a const static representation.
Multiple ASSERTions per method could still benefit from the caching, though.

Still need an answer to OT, though.

Comment: OT: I'm genuinely curious. Is there some reason you're not just using `__FILE__` for whatever nefarious purpose you're using `THIS_FILE__` for? It is, after all, defined by the standard to name whatever source file you're using it in.

Comment: As you yourself say, when used in this fashion, its going to reflect the name of the cpp file which is included. Is it going to work for a header like you expect it to?

Comment: @WhozCraig: [Dr. Dobbs' blog](http://www.drdobbs.com/an-exception-or-a-bug/184401686) recommends doing so in order to preserve ROM and not proliferate copies of the __FILE__ string.

Comment: @KarthikT: To be honest, I don't know. All my non-template source code is in .cpp's

Comment: Any compiler worth its salt will emit juts one copy of the string per file. I know mine does. Check what yours does, don't trust ancient articles that find wisdom in yet more ancient articles (1993, it's not even funny).

Comment: @n.m. I'm using gcc and clang. Searched around, but I couldn't find any way to check this. I'm not really sure how to examine my translation units after compile-time. I have a hunch that you're right, though, since they both are so good at optimizing other things (like when to open header files).

Comment: Two methods: 1. compile with `-S` flag, look at the assembly output; 2. `strings yourfile.o | fgrep yourfile.C`.

Comment: Did you try to place your macro in unnamed namespace ? `#define DEFINE_THIS_FILE namespace { static const char THIS_FILE__[] = __FILE__; }`

Comment: @borisbn That's it! Submit as an answer so I can select you. I had suspected namespaces might be key, but I forgot about the "unnamed" namespace being separate from global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your declaration in unnamed namespace

```
#define DEFINE_THIS_FILE namespace { static const char THIS_FILE__[] = __FILE__; }
```